# How can i edit .yml files in java?

Tags: java, yaml

is there a possible way to edit .yml files in java because i wanted to store information in it for a login and register plugin. I tried by checking if it contains the string but that did not work, i searched on java ducumentations but i could not find anything about YAML files.

Comment: [snakeyaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/), this may help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has no native YAML library, although there is a proposal for a [JSON library](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353).

You could use the [SnakeYAML](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml) library. You can find documentation on how to use it [here](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#SnakeYAML_Documentation). It is used in a few projects, including [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support .yml files out of the box. However there are a lot of 3rd party 'client' libraries which may help you: http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/,  http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/ or mentioned in earlier comment snakeyaml.

Comment: Jyaml is not supported anymore.